# Is 5 hours enough for changing flight from T3 to T1 in Bangkok Airport?

Tags: connecting-flights, bangkok, bkk

My flight will be landing in Bangkok at 9am at Terminal 3. My connecting flight will be at 1:55pm from Terminal 1.

Can someone please share how far Terminal 1 is from Terminal 3 at Bangkok airport and if 5 hours are sufficient to catch connecting flight?

Comment: BKK has only one terminal building and the concourses are numbered from A to G, so where are you getting these terminal numbers from?

Comment: Depending on whether the flights are on the same ticket and the airlines you may also be able to use the transfer desk.

Comment: Please clarify if both flights are on the same booking/ticket or not, and whether you have checked luggage.

Comment: For avoidance of doubt, are your flights at Bangkok-Suvarnabhumi (BKK) or Bangkok-Don Muang (DMK)?

Answer (score 2):

5 hours will be more than enough time to pass immigration, transfer terminals and enter the airport.

The two terminals are very close, nearly right next to each other and less than a 10 minute walk away from each other.

Comment: Thanks. Do i need to pass immigration to change terminals? Both of my flights are international, so i was wondering if terminals are close by then immigration should not be required.

Comment: @TravellingJuggernaut yes, you will go past immigration

Answer (score 0):

5 hours is almost always enough for catching a flight.

If the flights are on the same booking it's the airlines problem if your miss you flight because of delays. They will have to get you a new flight and will have to pay for accomodation and food if the wait is long.

If they're not on the same booking you'll have to get a ticket for another flight yourself if there are any delays.